# Drupal node 2-page content split

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

My employer requires certain pages on the website have a two page feature.
What this means is that some default content show up on the node_view page as normal but the second part should show up when a link is clicked.

This will be easy if I could do this across multiple nodes but the requirement is for all the data to be stored in one node but displayed across two pages.

I hacked together the following code:

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode){

$path = current_path();
$path_alias = drupal_lookup_path('alias',$path);

$links = array( 'test' => array('title'=>'my_link', 'query'=>'', 'href'=>"{$path_alias}/nextpage") );

$node->content['my_module'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'links__node__mymodule',
    '#links' => $links,
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('links', 'inline')),
);
}
```

That creates a hyperlink called **my_link** across the top of my content area - which is great.

The problem starts when I click the hyperlink. Supposing I am on **http://example.org/homepage** and I click the hyperlink, I expect to be redirected to **http://example.org/homepage/nextpage**. Also, I still want to maintain the view and edit tabs of the actual node I was on. However, Drupal correctly gives me a "page not found" error.

What's interesting is if I used **http://example.org/node/1** and visited **http://example.org/node/1/nextpage**, I don't get the issues I described above but the url is less descriptive.

To solve this problem, I am sure I have to extend **hook_menu** but I don't know how to account for any number of taxonomy terms leading up to the actual node title. So, I can't predict how many **%** I will need before the node title and then my **/nextpage**. However, I want **/nextpage** to still have the view and edit tabs of it's parent page.

This is all unexplored territory for me.

### Update

I found the following function which does a great job of returning the entire node path complete with taxonomies:

```
$path = current_path();
$path_alias = drupal_lookup_path('alias',$path);
```

What I don't know is how to take advantage of this in **hook_menu** to dynamically create **/nextpage** for my nodes.

Please remember, I don't really want **/nextpage** to be entirely independent of the original and actual Drupal node. When on /nextpage I want to be able to have access to the view, edit etc tabs of the node.

So, **/nextpage** effectively is just an extension of a Drupal node page.

Comment: Where does the content of the second page come from? Is it a node/field/something else?

Comment: The second pages' content can come from "cck" fields or it can the form part of a webform node

Answer (score 1):

I would check the node_menu() function to get some reference on how it's implemented.

Not sure on your taxonomy requirements so this might be insufficient but I'll go with what I understand.

But off the top of my head I'd go for something like:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['node/%node/nextpage'] = array(
    'title' => 'Next page',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK, // Makes it a tab on node/%node-pages
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_node_page_view', // Your page display function
    'page arguments' => array(1), // First will be a node object, second will be whatever value is passed in the  url
    // You should rip access callback and access arguments from node_menu()
  );

  return $items;
}
```

That should do something like what you are asking for.

It is also possible, easier and definitely recommended to do this with Panels/Pages (see also Chaos Tools) or arguably Views as they are quite capable of all this and generally a better way to work with Drupal's strengths than custom code.

**Updated**

To clarify I've simplified the menu hook and you should be able to use the below page view function. I still believe you would make a better solution using Panels and overriding node_view and such.

The MENU_LOCAL_TASK part in the menu hook should turn this into another tab along with View and Edit.

```
function mymodule_node_page_view($node) {
    die("It works: ".$node->title);
}
```

Hope that's more helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added to my original post - I found a drupal function which returns the full node path complete with taxonomies. Would you mind amending your code in accordance to my updated post, please?

Comment: Updated my post to hopefully clarify how it works with your needs.

I'm not 100% sure how it interacts with path aliases which is your additional issue. Try it and see would be my suggestion.

Comment: Updating you as a courtesy as your extensive answers, I found my plan to incorporate taxonomies etc into my "nextpage" solution just did not work. I eventually decided there is a hint in the edit, devel etc tabs not using full taxonomy + content title urls and instead just use a node/nid/edit type solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a quick way to do that. Using [views module](http://drupal.org/project/views).

In the fields section choose the field you wanna view. And in the arguments add the `nid`.

Then add the link to the node view you already created.

The final result `http://mysite/views-page/[nid]`

Hope this helps... Muhammad.